# Sub querys Count, resultado repetidos

Tags: mysql, count

Estoy realizando una query que me cuenta las veces que un id de la tabla B, aparece en la tabla A,  y cuando aparezca contar sus respectivos campos.

cabe destacar que no me sirve una tabla que se muestre asi

por lo que estoy intentando realizarla con sub querys

```
  SELECT e.provincia,
  (SELECT COUNT(t.estado) FROM transito AS t WHERE e.provincia = e.provincia AND 
  t.estado='RECUPERADO' 
  AND id_recolector='1500' GROUP BY t.id) AS 'RECUPERADO',
   (SELECT COUNT(t.estado) FROM transito AS t WHERE e.provincia = e.provincia AND t.estado='A- 
   CONFIRMAR' 
   AND id_recolector='1500' GROUP BY t.id) AS 'A-CONFIRMAR'

 FROM express AS e
 INNER JOIN transito t ON e.id_servidor=t.id 
 GROUP BY e.provincia
```

la cual me devuelve dicho valor,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se que estoy cerca de terminarla,solo que los resultados que arroja la subquery son erroneos
si alguien puede determinar en que estoy fallando o de que manera pudiera manejar mi query .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo en tu caso resolvería la consulta con una estructura como la siguiente.
`Sum(Case Condición then 1 else 0 end )`, Valida los registros que cumplen con la condición y regresa 1 si se cumple, al final las suma en el agrupado.

Si ya estas haciendo el cruce entonces puede ser una solución mas rápida que hacer subConsultas.

```sql
 SELECT e.provincia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.estado='RECUPERADO'  AND id_recolector='1500' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'RECUPERADO',
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.estado='A- CONFIRMAR'  AND id_recolector='1500' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'A-CONFIRMAR'
 FROM express AS e
    INNER JOIN transito t ON e.id_servidor=t.id 
 GROUP BY e.provincia
```

Comment: Muy bien eduardo, tu respuesta es la solucion. Gracias